# Why does President Trump add a second comma in this sentence to Kim Jong Un?

Tags: punctuation, comma-splices, oxford-comma, trumpism

In the President's letter to Kim Jong Un, I noticed a comma which confused me :

> I felt a wonderful dialogue was building up between you and me, and ultimately, it is only that dialogue that matters.

The first comma, to me, appears to be, potentially, a comma splice :

> I felt a wonderful dialogue was building up between you and me, ultimately it is only that dialogue that matters.

But the 'and' gets in the way of that.

What confuses me is the emphasis, particularly if I speak the sentence.

I would have expected either :

> I felt a wonderful dialogue was building up between you and me; and, ultimately, it is only that dialogue that matters.

or

> I felt a wonderful dialogue was building up between you and me. Ultimately, it is only that dialogue that matters.

I feel, myself, that the punctuation used is less powerful than the wording deserves.

Am I wrong ?

[image]

Comment: (1) There is no comma splice; a comma before 'and' introducing a second independent clause is normal though often optional. (2) The second comma here is totally acceptable, but again optional.

Comment: And no one mentions how it uses the nominally correct 'between you and me'?

Comment: @NigelJ are you suggesting the President of the United States did not write this letter himself?

Comment: Related: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/167425/understanding-having-to-do-with-this-most-important-summit

Comment: @NigelJ Thanks. But 'disrespect'? And 'disrespect the person'? How does naming or not entail disrespect?

Comment: How is the tag "trumpism" relevant? It reads: "for questions that specifically ask about the meaning, or the origin of expressions, attributed to or used by Donald Trump." That's not what the question is about.

Comment: @AleksandrH How is it _not_ about that? It's not about someone else. It's about his use of language.

Comment: Because "trumpism" is not about "Trump's grammar in X sentence" but about phrases or expressions that are attributable to him (e.g., covfefe, I imagine). The use of "and ultimately" doesn't really fit that criterion.

Comment: @AleksandrH that's not true, [according to the BBC (or rather the republican analyst they cited)](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-42738881):  _Trumpism is "what the president believes on any particular moment on any particular day about any particular subject," says Ron Christie, a Republican analyst who worked in the White House of George W Bush._

Comment: @JJJ I'm talking about trumpism as defined on the forums. Read the tag.

Comment: @AleksandrH the tag reads: _for questions that specifically **ask about the meaning**, or the origin **of expressions**, attributed to or **used by the 45th President of the United States, Donald Trump.**_ What does he, or more likely the staffer who wrote the letter, mean by the comma? Maybe he did write (or *dictate*) it himself but had to pause a few times, because you know, it reminded him of how a **wonderful dialogue was building up between** the two love birds, just moments ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The letter combines two independent clauses, the second of which begins with an adverb:

> Ultimately, it is only that dialogue that matters.

The comma before the *and* is the standard comma before a coordinating conjunction joining independent clauses. The second preserves the comma before the initial adverb.

I didn’t find this punctuation remarkable or confusing. The Writing Center of the University of Wisconsin-Madison [suggests](https://writing.wisc.edu/Handbook/CoordConj.html), however, if there is a chance of ambiguity,

> When either independent clause in a compound sentence contains a comma to set off introductory or non-essential elements, a reader may be confused by a comma before a coordinating conjunction. In this case, a semicolon may replace the comma.
>
> > *The figures at elite universities, particularly, are enough to cause sticker shock; yet the current increases at many schools are the lowest in a decade.*

Note a writer *may* choose a semicolon, but it is not obligatory.